# ajax call does not calls for some reason

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, ajax

It seems that everything is entered correctly, but how many tried - nothing works. Please tell me what may be wrong here. My assumptions are that

1. or something is wrong with the url and it just can't get to the method.
2. maybe the problem is related to the fact that I'm creating Posts and I'm trying to take the data from Postsss (although this seems to be the way it should be done.

The table is simply not populated with data. That is, the ajax method itself does not receive them for some reason, but why if I specified the correct address in the url?

Controller method

```
using Project.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Photos()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> Photosss()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
            var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(response.Content);

            var jAlbumsArray = content.ToObject<List<JObject>>();

            foreach (var obj in jAlbumsArray)
            {
                if (jAlbumsArray.IndexOf(obj) == 1)
                {
                    foreach (var p in obj.Properties())
                    {
                        if (p.Name == "title")
                            obj["title"] = "this title is changed";  //replace some data
                    }
                }
            }

            var jAlbums = JArray.FromObject(jAlbumsArray);


            var albums = jAlbums.Select(x => new Photos
            {
                Id = (int)x["id"],
                AlbumId = (int)x["albumId"],
                Title = (string)x["title"],
                Url = (string)x["url"],
                ThumbnailUrl = (string)x["thumbnailUrl"]
            }).ToList();

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(albums);

            return Content(json, "application/json");
        }

    }
}
```

In View

```
        <table id="photosTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>AlbumId</th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Url</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        
ajax call 

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

    @section scripts{
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#photosTable").DataTable(
                    {
                        ajax: {
                            url: "Home/Postsss",
                            type: "GET",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            datatype: "json",
                            dataSrc: "data"
                        },
                        "columns": [
                            { data: "AlbumId" },
                            { data: "Id" },
                            { data: "Title" },
                            { data: "Url" }
    
                        ]
                    })
                }
            }
        </script>
    
    }
```

Comment: shouldnt your url be `Home/Photosss` or am i understanding the question wrong? `Home/Postsss` seems like an url you didnt define in your controller. Anyway you can always check your developer tools of the browser you are using and view your network traffic

Comment: yes, thanks, its my mistake. I changed, but still nothing changed. in the network traffic I did not find the photosss call

Comment: @memento does below answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#photosTable").DataTable(
            {
                ajax: {
                    url: "/Home/Photosss",
                    type: "GET",
                    datatype: "json",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                "columns": [
                    { data: "AlbumId" },
                    { data: "Id" },
                    { data: "Title" },
                    { data: "Url" },
                    { data: "ThumbnailUrl" }
                ]
            })
    }
    );
```

Changes: 1. Add **ThumbnailUrl** column in table header. 2. Remove **content type** header. 3. Make **dataSrc** value to emtpy string as you're not getting back data object.